# Saver.save is getting slower and slower in each fold

Tags: python, tensorflow, time

I am using tensorflow and I have developer a deep multilayer feedforward model. To be sure about the performance of the model, I decided to use it in 10-fold cross validation. In each fold I create a new instance of the neural network, call the train and the predict functions.

In each fold I call the following codes:

```
for each fold:
         nn= ffNN(hidden_nodes, epochs, learning_rate, saveFrequency, save_path, decay, decay_step, decay_factor, stop_loss, keep_probability, regularization_factor,minimum_cost,activation_function,batch_size,shuffle,stopping_iteration)
         nn.initialize(x_size)
         nn.train(X,y)
         nn.predict(X_test)
```

in `ffNN` file I have the initialization and train and predict functions as follow:

nn.train:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
for each epoch:
       for each batch:
          _ , loss = session.run([self.optimizer,self.loss],feed_dict={self.X:X1, self.y:y})
       if epoch % save_frequency == 0:
            saver.save(session,save_path)
sess.close()
```

The problem is in `saver.save`, in each fold it takes longer and longer to save. Although I create all of the variables from the scratch, I don't know what is making it dependent on the folds and make the saving takes longer and longer.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The code for building the model `nn.initialize` is as follow:

```
 self.X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, x_size], name='XValue')
 self.y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, y_size], name='yValue')
 with tf.variable_scope("initialization", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    w_in, b_in = init_weights((x_size, self.hidden_nodes))
    h_out = self.forwardprop(self.X, w_in, b_in, self.keep_prob,self.activation_function)
    l2_norm = tf.add(tf.nn.l2_loss(w_in), tf.nn.l2_loss(b_in))
    w_out, b_out = init_weights((self.hidden_nodes, y_size))
    l2_norm = tf.add(tf.nn.l2_loss(w_out), l2_norm)
    l2_norm = tf.add(tf.nn.l2_loss(b_out), l2_norm)
    self.yhat = tf.add(tf.matmul(h_out, w_out), b_out)
    self.mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=self.y, predictions=self.yhat)
    self.loss = tf.add(self.mse,self.regularization_factor * l2_norm)
    self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to build the model?

Comment: @gorjan Just added

Comment: Just answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described in the question the problem is not in `saver.save`, but the computational graph getting bigger and bigger instead. Thus, the saving takes more time. Make sure to structure the code in the following way:

```
for each fold:
    # Clear the previous computational graph
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    # Then build the graph
    nn = ffNN()
    # Create the saver
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # Create a session
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Initialize the variables in the graph
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # Train the model
        for each epoch:
            for each batch:
                nn.train_on_batch()
            if epoch % save_frequency == 0:
                saver.save(sess,save_path)
```

Comment: Isn't creating a new ffNN clears the graph? Also I added the session part that I create them each time I'm calling ffNN

Comment: No. You always have to reset the default graph before building a new graph. Follow the chronology of creating and running stuff that I have described.

Comment: Was that of help?

Comment: it returns error: `ValueError: No variables to save` if I call `saver = tf.train.Saver()` after `tf.reset_default_graph()`

Comment: `saver = tf.train.Saver()` can't raise that error since it is not saving anything. It just instantiates a train saver. My main point is that you have to reset the default graph before building a new one. If you reset the default graph, create a saver, create a new graph, start a session, initialize all variables, train the model, save the model, you can't get that error. The error you are getting suggest that you have tried to save the model before building the model.

Comment: I reseted the default graph at the end of each fold, and the problem solved. Thanks.
But the way you have written in the answer gives me error. I don't know why.

Comment: Reseting the graph at the end is a slippery slope. I'm highly against it. However, if it works for you in this case go for it. Besides, reseting the graph at the end shouldn't make a difference. Good luck!